# Is Deuteronomy 23:23 a free will offering?

Tags: law, deuteronomy, moses

KJV Deuteronomy 23 : 23

> That which is gone out of thy lips thou shalt keep and perform; even a freewill offering, ***according as thou hast vowed unto the LORD thy God***, which thou hast promised with thy mouth.

Could the above offering be a free will offering  seeing it also involves a vow

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "Yes" - note the previous verses:

> Deut 23:21-23 - **If** you make a vow to the LORD your God, do not be
> slow to keep it, because He will surely require it of you, and you
> will be guilty of sin. But **if** you refrain from making a vow, you
> will not be guilty of sin. Be careful to follow through on what comes
> from your lips, because you have freely vowed to the LORD your God
> with your own mouth.

That is, one was free to either make a vow or not.  However, if one makes a vow, then the law stated that the vow must be fulfilled expeditiously.

Note the Pulpit commentary:

> Verses 21-23. - A vow to the Lord, once made, was to be religiously
> kept; the Lord would require it, and to refuse or neglect to pay it
> would be held a sin. No one, however, was under any obligation to vow
> ie, **that was to be a purely voluntary act**. That which is gone out of thy lips thou shalt keep and perform... according as thou hast vowed
> unto the Lord thy God of free-will (נְדָבָה, spontaneously). (For the
> law concerning vows in general, see Leviticus 27, and Numbers 30.)
> Deuteronomy 23:21